# Is there a tool to read a subversion repository via .net?

Tags: .net, svn

I'm using a filestystem based (no apache or web server) subversion repository.

Since we moved over to subversion our change log on the application has converted to be commit notes in subversion.  I would like it if it were possible for either at design time, I call a tool that scrapes the latest commit notes out of the subversion repository, or if at run-time the application can scrape the latest commit notes out of the subversion repository to display to the user or a developer.

I prefer .net and open source if possible, but would consider other possibilities if any exist.

Is there a tool to read a subversion repository via .net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, it's [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, SharpSVN is being maintained by Collabnet so I guess it is the best option.

http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/